# R markdown - Can I suppress leading linefeeds/whitespace in output from basic code chunk functions?

Tags: r, r-markdown

High school stats teacher here -- I'm creating R markdown summaries of the answers/approaches to various labs and assignments where I demonstrate the R code necessary to support the necessary queries/analyses.

It's working great, but I have one minor formatting challenge I haven't been able to sort out. In my markdown files, I intermingle commentary with the code, and so have formatted textual intros/outros to various code blocks. In some cases, I simply want to show the function call followed by the output, and some functions produce a bit of leading whitespace that if possible, I'd like to remove/suppress. Here is an example:

[image: Example A - table function]

As I say, it's a minor quibble, but the leading whitespace is a bit ungainly with the shorter function responses, and if it's possible to remove it with a little heretofore undiscovered setting of option(s) or code, I'd love to be able to deal with it. Thanks in advance for your help.

Details of my world: using R Studio on Posit, doing R markdown with knitr and outputting to HTML.

Comment: Do you mean the position of table or the white space over cat and dog?

Comment: The whitespace over cat and dog.  "Titling" it as suggested by the first answer is a good way to deal with it in my case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way `table()` results are printed when you don't name the argument.  If you named it you'd see something different, e.g.
`table(species = animal$type)` would print as

```
species
cat dog
182 291
```

`knitr` does provide a few ways to manipulate output.  In this case, the easiest might be to provide a `knit_print.table` method, e.g. just define the function

```
knit_print.table <- function(x, ...) {
  lines <- capture.output(print(x, ...))
  cat(lines[lines != ""], sep = "\n")
}
```

and `knitr` will drop blank lines when it prints.

Comment: Perfect -- in my case, just providing the "title" will make it look better and that's sufficient.  The intervening print table function is also a good idea. Thanks so much!